# Cannot deploy Spring App to Websphere

Tags: spring, websphere

I've been developing an application to tomcat during development phase.  As we're moving forward, my client wants to be deployed to websphere.  I'm attempting to do so on websphere 8.5, but for some reason I seem to be running into problems.  Tomcat is easy, I'm just dropping in the war and everything works like it should.  Websphere is a different story.  I keep getting the following error when I try to hit my application:

```
Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}
```

I've been doing some research and aside from the one line below, I don't notice anything strange in the logs.  The admin console says the application is running with no problems.

```
SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [app#app.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

My application is configured using Java Config files instead of the traditional XML and I'm half guessing this is part of the problem?

I found a blog post saying that there were some server settings that needed to be applied.  I've tried those with no success:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.mapFiltersToAsterisk=true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.removetrailingservletpathslash=true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility=true
```

I'm at a loss, does anyone have any ideas?

Due to some followup, I'll post my web.xml and WebappInitializer:

```
@Order(2)
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ApplicationConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, JpaConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, MailConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
        registration.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "default");
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
        <!-- Map all errors to Spring MVC handler method. See CustomErrorController.generalError() -->
        <error-page>
            <location>/generalError</location>
        </error-page>
        <session-config>
          <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
       </session-config>
       <display-name>eua</display-name>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: What is in FFDC logs? How did your class loader policy configured?

Comment: Nothing is in the FFDC logs unless I try to hit {context}/x.  When I hit the root, nothing goes there.  For class loader policy I tried many combinations.  I read somewhere that parent_last was supposed to work, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you installed all fix packs for WebSphere? There have been some fixes in the realm of the `ServletContextInitializer` stuff. In theory it should just work. How are you creating your war/jar file? Is the `WebAppInitializer` in WEB-INF/classes or inside a jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: It's a brand new deployment of websphere dev version.   When I installed I applied all the relevant patches.  I'm creating my war using the standard maven configuration.  I believe it may wrap up the application inside a jar In the WEB-INF lib dir

Comment: Its not inside a jar, its in the war directly in WEB-INF/classes:    app.war\WEB-INF\classes\org\name\app\config\WebAppInitializer.class

Comment: See https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/8758/servletcontainerinitializer-working-in-websphere-application-server-80-but-not-in-855/. Appears to be fixed in the most recent fixpack or use the workaround.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not terribly happy about my solution, but it works for the time being.  Websphere's support of web.xml-less initialization is a bit sub-standard.  Even replies from their techs were unhelpful.  In the end I had to move a bit of the spring initialization to the web.xml.  I was still able to configure most of my JPA, security, and Web features via config files, but I had to give Spring a bit of kickstart.  Below is my altered web.xml for anyone that is interested.  Thanks everyone for the help and guidance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <!-- Map all errors to Spring MVC handler method. See CustomErrorController.generalError() -->
    <error-page>
        <location>/generalError</location>
    </error-page>
    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <display-name>app</display-name>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
   </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.proj.config.ApplicationConfig 
                    org.proj.config.DefaultDataSourceConfig
                    org.proj.config.JpaConfig
                    org.proj.config.SecurityConfig
                    org.proj.config.MailConfig
                    org.proj.config.WebMvcConfig
       </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
         </init-param>
          <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
               and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
          <init-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>org.proj.config.ApplicationConfig 
                           org.proj.config.DefaultDataSourceConfig
                           org.proj.config.JpaConfig
                           org.proj.config.SecurityConfig
                           org.proj.config.MailConfig
                           org.proj.config.WebMvcConfig  
               </param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm going to try your approach and let you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to try making sure you have all the latest websphere fixpacks installed.  Someone commented a few weeks ago that a recent patch fixed this issue.  If not, my solution did end up working for my project.

Comment: I'm working with IBM BPM and there are fixes every week, with your solution is working so I voted you up. Thx

Answer (score 5):

use @Configuration annotation on the WebAppInitializer  class

```
@Configuration 
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(SpringWebConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

 }
```

Comment: Where can I get dependencies for container and SpringWebConfig ?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. The Websphere has some default limit on the number of classes that can be scanned. And this SpringBoot main class was probably not within that range. In my case, the issue was resolved when I set this JVM property -Dclassinfocachesize=10000  (Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine> Generic JVM arguments >)  and restart WAS

Answer (score 3):

For me working solution for **IBM WAS ND 8.5.0** was to implement directly interface WebApplicationInitializer:

> To deploy a Spring Boot application to Weblogic you must ensure that your servlet initializer directly implements WebApplicationInitializer (even if you extend from a base class that already implements it).

[SpringBoot 74.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic)

Comment: you amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both adding @Configuration annotation and directly implementing WebApplicationInitializer can resolve this issue. (Tested for Websphere 8.5.0.2)

Comment: Where can I get more info about how to directly implement WebApplicationInitializer? It is about overriding on startup method?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue too. My Spring MVC (Spring 4.3) Rest application was working on Jboss, but when I tried deploying on Websphere 8.5.5 I got the same error: **SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [app#app.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath**. I tried all the options suggested in this post and other posts, but nothing worked out. Finally I found the issue. When I created the Spring MVC Rest application I used maven archetype to create the project and it created the Spring MVC application with blank web.xml. As I planned to use Spring4, java based initialization, I left arechetype created web.xml like that and didn't configure my dispatcherServlet in web.xml. Jboss was intelligent enough to ignore blank web.xml and finding java initializer class and bringing the application up. Where as the same application deployed on WebSphere 8.5.5, WebSphere found the blank web.xml and looking for the DispatcherServlet info in the web.xml and not looking for the java initializer class. After removing the web.xml and redeploying the application is up on WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is fixed by APAR PM85177 for WebSphere ND. The fix is integrated in WAS8.0.0.8 and following version.

Comment: This one clue/answer changed my pain into enormous joy. I wish i could promote this answer with more votes. Thanks ze zhang.