# SpringBootServlerInitializer is root caues of exception while deploy on websphere?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere

I try to deploy my application on spring-boot to webspere server.
There is ok status when try to deploy with this start class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But, there is error message if I try to add SprigBootServlerInitializer

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TEST</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring-boot dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>TEST</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How to avoid error and deploy to websphere?

*tried to ovverride configure method, but with same result.

Error logs:

> [9/21/18 13:44:22:158 MSK] 000000b7 AppBinaryProc I   ADMA7021I:
>   Distribution of application TEST_war completed successfully. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:168 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:168 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/TEST.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:168 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/TEST_war.ear. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:169 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deltas/TEST_war/delta-1537526656520.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:169 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/was.module.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:170 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/was.webmodule.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:170 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/cus/TEST_war/cver/BASE/cu.xml. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:170 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/cus/TEST_war/cver/BASE/controlOpDefs.xml. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:170 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:171 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/application.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:171 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/TEST.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:171 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/blas/TEST_war/bver/BASE/bla.xml. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:172 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/TEST.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/web-fragment.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:172 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/ibm-application-runtime.props.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:172 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/deployment.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:173 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/TEST.war/WEB-INF/web.xml.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:173 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/cus/TEST_war/cver/BASE/cu-ref.xml. [9/21/18
>   13:44:22:173 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/META-INF/was.policy.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:174 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/applications/TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war/TEST.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
>   [9/21/18 13:44:22:174 MSK] 000000b7 FileRepositor A   ADMR0016I: User
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin modified document
>   cells/wasNode01Cell/nodes/wasNode01/serverindex.xml. [9/21/18
>   13:45:19:582 MSK] 000000b5 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1008I: An attempt is
>   made to start the TEST_war application. (User ID =
>   defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin) [9/21/18 13:45:19:590 MSK] 000000b5
>   CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit
>   WebSphere:cuname=TEST_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=TEST_war. [9/21/18
>   13:45:19:630 MSK] 000000b5 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting
>   application: TEST_war [9/21/18 13:45:19:630 MSK] 000000b5
>   ApplicationMg A   WSVR0203I: Application: TEST_war  Application build
>   level: 1.0-SNAPSHOT [9/21/18 13:45:20:343 MSK] 000000b5 wtp
>   W
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector
>   locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class
>   ] in [ WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar ]: [ null ] [9/21/18
>   13:45:20:345 MSK] 000000b5 wtp           W
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector
>   locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class ]
>   in [ WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar ]: [ null ] [9/21/18
>   13:45:20:346 MSK] 000000b5 wtp           W
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector
>   locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [
>   module-info.class ] in [ WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar ]: [ null ]
>   [9/21/18 13:45:20:939 MSK] 000000b5 webapp        I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I:
>   Loading Web Module: Tomcat Host Manager springboot.Application.
>   [9/21/18 13:45:20:947 MSK] 000000b5 WASSessionCor I
>   SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new
>   session context for application key default_host/test [9/21/18
>   13:45:22:282 MSK] 000000b5 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class
>   in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
>           ...
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/21/18 13:45:22:286 MSK] 000000b5 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource
>   META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class
>   in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:765)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:606)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
>           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>           ...
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:768)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:464)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1137)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/21/18 13:45:22:288 MSK] 000000b5 ecs           W
>   com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
>   unable to open input stream for resource module-info.class in archive
>   WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
>                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
>           ...
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
>
> [9/21/18 13:45:32:898 MSK] 000000b5 webapp        I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [TEST_war#TEST.war]:.2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on
>   classpath [9/21/18 13:45:33:481 MSK] 000000b5 SpringApplica E
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication reportFailure Application
>   run failed
>                                    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding
>   method
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile;)Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter;"
>   during creation of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420":
>   loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825" of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420"
>   and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@dd9c34e1" of
>   class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory"
>   have different types for the method signature
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:336)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:215)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:198)
>            ...
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when
>   overriding method
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile;)Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter;"
>   during creation of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420":
>   loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825" of class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420"
>   and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@dd9c34e1" of
>   class
>   "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory"
>   have different types for the method signature
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:339)
>           at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
>           at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:315)
>           at java.lang.invoke.DirectHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_L(DirectHandle.java:302)
>           at java.lang.invoke.AsTypeHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(AsTypeHandle.java:49)
>           at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.resolveInvokeDynamic(MethodHandle.java:841)
>           ... 124 more
>
> [9/21/18 13:45:33:487 MSK] 000000b5 webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E:
>   Failure to initialize Web application Tomcat Host Manager
>   springboot.Application [9/21/18 13:45:33:490 MSK] 000000b5
>   DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, TEST.war, of application,
>   TEST_war.ear/deployments/TEST_war, failed to start [9/21/18
>   13:45:33:492 MSK] 000000b5 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error
>   occurred starting, TEST_war [9/21/18 13:45:33:492 MSK] 000000b5
>   ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: TEST_war [9/21/18
>   13:45:33:499 MSK] 000000b5 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application
>   stopped: TEST_war [9/21/18 13:45:33:501 MSK] 000000b5 CompositionUn E 
>   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=TEST_war in BLA
>   WebSphere:blaname=TEST_war failed to start. [9/21/18 13:45:33:501 MSK]
>   000000b5 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object:
>   WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=wasNode01,version=8.5.5.13,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=wasNode01Cell,spec=1.0
>   because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to
>   load webapp: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: loading
>   constraint violation when overriding method
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter&#40;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile&#59;&#41;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter&#59;&quot;
>   during creation of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420&quot;:
>   loader
>   &quot;java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@d1c57825&quot;
>   of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$999/000000002447A420&quot;
>   and loader
>   &quot;com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@dd9c34e1&quot;
>   of class
>   &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory&quot;
>   have different types for the method signature

Comment: If you plan to develop for Liberty, I'd strongly recommend to ditch spring and use Java EE. It is much easier to use and better integrated with all the features that Liberty already provides. Using spring you have to bundle tons of redundant and unnecessary jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working solution for IBM WAS ND 8.5.0 was to implement directly interface WebApplicationInitializer:

To deploy a Spring Boot application to Weblogic you must ensure that your servlet initializer directly implements WebApplicationInitializer (even if you extend from a base class that already implements it).

[Cannot deploy Spring App to Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714642/cannot-deploy-spring-app-to-websphere)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override below method to run as web application

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
```

Comment: Added, but there is error message

ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory&amp;quot&#59; have different types for the method signature

Comment: Do you added below dependency.<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
  </dependency>

Comment: @shudham jain yes, sure. Updated issue description, added pom.xml

Comment: Use provided dependency instead of existing. <parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

Comment: Use import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

Comment: What error you are getting if not overriding configure() method.

Comment: Can you share you whole main class

Comment: &quot;com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@dd9c34e1&quot; of class &quot;org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory&quot; have different types for the method signature

Comment: @shibham jain in issue description I provided all code in main class.

Comment: Can you try to deploy app with some unique context root. Default is / so try /test